# grep few columns from a file to another file in shell

Tags: shell

The following file is present in **file1.txt**:

```
mudId|~|mudType|~|mudNAme|~|mudDate|~|mudEndDate
100|~|Balance|~|Abc|~|21-09-2020|~|22-09-2020
101|~|Clone|~|Bcd|~|11-07-2020|~|12-07-2020
102|~|Ledger|~|Def|~|12-06-2019|~|13-06-2019
```

How to grep only the columns **`mudId, mudType and mudDate`** with all the rows into another file?
The columns are separated by `|~|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To meet your criteria of specifying the field names from the heading row, you can use `awk` utilizing a Regular Expression as the Field-Separator variable (e.g. `"[|][~][|]"`). For the first record (line), read the field names as array indexes and set the value to the current field index. For your second rule, simply output the field value captured in your array that corresponds to the strings `"mudId"`, `"mudType"` and `"mudDate"`.

For example you can do:

```
awk '
    BEGIN  { FS="[|][~][|]"; OFS="|~|" }
    FNR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) arr[$i]=i; next } 
           { print $arr["mudId"], $arr["mudType"], $arr["mudDate"] }
' file
```

(**note:** the above intentionally generalizes to meet your criteria where you want to specify the string names of the fields to output)

If you simply want to write fields 1, 2, & 4 to a new file, you would do:

```
awk -v FS="[|][~][|]" -v OFS="|~|" 'FNR>1 {print $1,$2,$4}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

Simply copy/middle-mouse paste the above into an xterm where `file` is in the current directory, e.g.

```
$ awk '
>     BEGIN  { FS="[|][~][|]"; OFS="|~|" }
>     FNR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) arr[$i]=i; next }
>            { print $arr["mudId"], $arr["mudType"], $arr["mudDate"] }
> ' file
100|~|Balance|~|21-09-2020
101|~|Clone|~|11-07-2020
102|~|Ledger|~|12-06-2019
```

(**note:** if you want the new file space-delimited, just remove `OFS="|~|"`)

or

```
$ awk -v FS="[|][~][|]" -v OFS="|~|" 'FNR>1 {print $1,$2,$4}' file
100|~|Balance|~|21-09-2020
101|~|Clone|~|11-07-2020
102|~|Ledger|~|12-06-2019
```

To write the contents to a new filename, just redirect the output to a new filename (e.g. for the last line above, add `' file > newfile`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is fixed by `mudId|~|mudType|~|mudNAme|~|mudDate|~|mudEndDate`, try this:

```
sed 's/|~|/\t/g' file1.txt | awk '{print $1"|~|"$2"|~|"$4}'
```

you should change `\t` to other character which will not occur in your **file1.txt** if the `\t` would exist in **file1.txt**, and then add `-F'\t'` after `awk`.

Comment: Nice substitution! You can also use `gsub()`, e.g. `awk -v FS="," -v OFS="|~|" 'FNR>1 {gsub(/[|][~][|]/,","); print $1,$2,$4}' file`